# Displaying two digit numbers in assembly?

Tags: assembly

I am completely new to assembly programming. In of the examples at classwork its required to add two numbers and display the sum, what I find cryptic is display the sum when its a two digit number.
Here's my code.

```
    mov al,num1
    mov bl,num2

    add al,bl

    add ax,3030h

    mov dl,ah
    mov ah,02h
    int 21h

    mov dl,al
    mov ah,02h
    int 21h

    mov ah,4ch
    int 21h
```

While the addition might result in a packed number, how do I unpack it and display as two different numbers in decimal?

Comment: Divide by 10 and display the quotient and the remainder separately.

Answer (score 3):

I'm also new to assembly. 
But I think this will help you.

```
 
.model small
.stack 100h
.data 
    msg1 db "Enter number 1:$"
    msg2 db "Enter number 2:$"
    msg3 db "Sum is:$"
    no1 db 0
    no2 db 0
    mysum db 0
    rem db 0


.code 
    mov ax,@data 
    mov ds,ax

;print msg 1
    mov dx,offset msg1 
    mov ah,09h
    int 21h

;read input no1
    mov ah,01h
    int 21h
    sub al,48
    mov no1,al

;print new line
    mov dl,10
    mov ah,02h
    int 21h

;print msg2
    mov dx,offset msg2
    mov ah,09h
    int 21h

;read input 2
    mov ah,01h
    int 21h
    sub al,48
    mov no2,al

;print new line 
    mov dl,10
    mov ah,02h
    int 21h

;print msg3
    mov dx,offset msg3
    mov ah,09h
    int 21h

;add two numbers
    mov dl,no1
    add dl,no2
    ;moving the sum to mysum
    mov mysum,dl

    ;clear AH to use for reminder
    mov ah,00
    ;moving sum to al
    mov al,mysum
    ;take bl=10
    mov bl,10
    ;al/bl --> twodigit number/10 = decemel value
    div bl
    ;move reminder to rim
    mov rem,ah
    ;to print (al) we move al to dl
    mov dl,al
    add dl,48
    mov ah,02h
    int 21h

    ;to print the reminder
    mov dl,rem
    add dl,48
    mov ah,02h
    int 21h

    mov ax,4c00h
    int 21h
end
```

here what I've done is I took the total and move it to al that can keep it. 
then I divide it by 10 and print the quotient and reminder. 
If you feel problem. you can ask. Thank you !

Comment: `div bl` calculates `AX / BL`, not `AL / BL`.  *That's* why you have to zero AH first.  Storing the remainder in AH is a write-only operation.  And BTW, you can just `add` into AL in the first place; you don't need a `mysum` static storage location.  Use registers to hold your data, that's what they're for.

Answer (score -1):

A simple assembly program to add two number as follows :

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
 var1 db ?  
 var2 db ? 
 str db 0ah,0dh,'sum: $'      
.code
main proc             
    mov ax, @data  ; initialization of data segment
    mov ds, ax       

    mov ah, 1      ; input  var1 and var2
    int 21h
    mov var1, al  
    int 21h   
    mov var2, al

    mov bl, var1
    mov cl, var2           
    add bl, cl     ; addition of var1 and var2     

    mov al, bl           ;
    mov ah,0          
    aaa               

    mov bx,ax          
    add bh,30h
    add bl,30h

    mov ah,9
    lea dx,str
    int 21h

    mov ah,2
    mov dl,bh       ;showing sum 
    int 21h  

    mov ah,2
    mov dl,bl
    int 21h   
 main endp
```