# Assembly Language code to count different characters but when any counter exceeds 9, it prints different symbols instead of that specific number

Tags: loops, assembly, input, emulation, x86-16

```
.MODEL small
.STACK 100h

.DATA   
;Variables to store total counts

countAlpha DB ?
countNum DB '0'
countOperator DB '0'

;Message to be displayed with total counts

mesg1 DB "You entered:$"
alphaChars DB ":    Alphabet Characters$"
numChars DB ":  Numbers$"
operators DB ": Arithematic Characters$"



.CODE

MAIN PROC 

    MOV ax,@Data
    MOV ds,ax


    MOV countAlpha ,'0' 

    MOV Cx, 20
    Loop1:


     MOV ah,01
     int 21h  

     CMP al,'A'
     JGE goToAlpha


     CMP al,'0'
     JGE goToNum


     CMP al,'+'
     JE gotoOp 

     CMP al,'-'
     JE gotoOp 


     CMP al,'*'
     JE gotoOp 

     CMP al,'/'
     JE gotoOp 


     Empty:



     CMP al,0DH
     JE CountNothing      

    loop Loop1



     goToAlpha:
        CMP al,'Z'
        JLE gotToAlphaCount

      gotToAlphaCount:
        INC countAlpha  
        JMP Empty

      goToNum:
        CMP al,'9'
        JLE gotToNumCount

      gotToNumCount:
        INC countNum  
        JMP Empty


      gotoOp:
        INC countOperator
        JMP Empty           

    CountNothing:




       MOV ah,02
       MOV dl,0dh
       int 21h

       MOV dl,0ah
       int 21h


       MOV ah,09
       Lea dx,mesg1
       int 21h

       ;line feed
       MOV ah,02
       MOV dl,0dh
       int 21h

       MOV dl,0ah
       int 21h



       MOV bl,countAlpha
       MOV ah,02
       MOV dl,bl
       int 21h


       MOV ah,09
       Lea dx,alphaChars
       int 21h



       MOV ah,02
       MOV dl,0dh
       int 21h

       MOV dl,0ah
       int 21h


       MOV bl,countNum
       MOV ah,02
       MOV dl,bl
       int 21h            


       MOV ah,09
       Lea dx,numChars
       int 21h



       MOV ah,02
       MOV dl,0dh
       int 21h

       MOV dl,0ah
       int 21h


       MOV bl,countOperator
       MOV ah,02
       MOV dl,bl
       int 21h            

       MOV ah,09
       Lea dx,operators
       int 21h



       MOV ah,4ch
       int 21h      





    MAIN ENDP
END MAIN
```

Comment: i use emulator to code in Assembly language.

Comment: You are using int 21 ah=2 to do the printing.  That will print exactly 1 character.  If you tell it to print [ascii](http://www.asciitable.com/) character 49 (aka `1`) then that's what it prints.  If you tell it to print ascii character 58 (aka `:`) then that's what it prints.  If you want to print 2 characters (for example `10`) using int 21 ah=2, you'll need to call it twice.  Once for each character.  See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22909589/displaying-two-digit-numbers-in-assembly).

Comment: to add to David comment, you are initializing your counters to value 48, that's the value of ASCII character for digit zero (`48 == '0'`).

Comment: Yes, but I am unable to code the thing I want? Biy confused